# NullPointerException caught when writing to BigTable using Apache Beam's dataflow sdk

Tags: nullpointerexception, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm using `Apache's Beam` sdk version `0.2.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT`
 and trying to pull data to a bigtable with the `Dataflow` runner. Unfortunately I'm getting `NullPointerException` when executing my dataflow pipeline where I'm using `BigTableIO.Write` as my sink. Already checked my `BigtableOptions` and the parameters are fine, according to my needs.

Basically, I create and in some point of my pipeline I have the step to write the `PCollection<KV<ByteString, Iterable<Mutation>>>` to my desired bigtable:

```java
final BigtableOptions.Builder optionsBuilder =
    new BigtableOptions.Builder().setProjectId(System.getProperty("PROJECT_ID"))
        .setInstanceId(System.getProperty("BT_INSTANCE_ID"));

// do intermediary steps and create PCollection<KV<ByteString, Iterable<Mutation>>> 
// to write to bigtable

// modifiedHits is a PCollection<KV<ByteString, Iterable<Mutation>>>
modifiedHits.apply("writting to big table", BigtableIO.write()
    .withBigtableOptions(optionsBuilder).withTableId(System.getProperty("BT_TABLENAME")));

p.run();
```

When executing the pipeline, I got the `NullPointerException`, pointing out exactly to the BigtableIO class at the `public void processElement(ProcessContext c)` method:

```java
(6e0ccd8407eed08b): java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigtable.BigtableIO$Write$BigtableWriterFn.processElement(BigtableIO.java:532)
```

I checked this method is processing all elements before to write on bigtable, but not sure why I'm getting such exception overtime I execute this pipeline. According to the code below, this method uses `bigtableWriter` attribute to process each `c.element()`, but I can't even set a breakpoint to debug where is exactly the `null`. Any kind of advice or suggestion of how to solve this issue?

```java
@ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
    checkForFailures();
    Futures.addCallback(
        bigtableWriter.writeRecord(c.element()), new WriteExceptionCallback(c.element()));
    ++recordsWritten;
  }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify a few things: 1) What version of the SDK are you using? 2) What runner are you using? (direct runner, Spark, Flink, Dataflow?) If it's Dataflow, could you give the job ID?

Comment: @jkff thanks for the comment. Yes, just edited my question, including the versions. So, yes, I'm using Dataflow runner. Its job id is 2016-09-13_08_29_14-14276852956124203982

Comment: I looked up the job and its classpath, and if I'm not mistaken it looks like you're using version 0.3.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT of beam-sdks-java-{core,io}, but version 0.2.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT of google-cloud-dataflow-java. I believe the issue is because of this - you have to use the same version (more details: BigtableIO in version 0.3.0 uses \@Setup and \@Teardown methods, but runner 0.2.0 does not support them yet).

Comment: @jkff exactly that was the problem, just fixed here. Thank you.

Comment: @jkff – please move your comment into an answer so that it can be accepted and this question can be marked closed. Thank you for solving the problem!

Comment: @MishaBrukman Done, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up the job and its classpath, and if I'm not mistaken it looks like you're using version `0.3.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT` of `beam-sdks-java-{core,io}`, but `version 0.2.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT` of `google-cloud-dataflow-java`.

I believe the issue is because of this - you have to use the same version (more details: BigtableIO in version 0.3.0 uses `@Setup` and `@Teardown` methods, but runner 0.2.0 does not support them yet).